# Why does setInterval seem to have scope issues in my jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm sorry this isn't more specific, but I'm having trouble isolating the issue.

I've written [a very simple jQuery plugin](https://github.com/bigdave/ghostfaceScrollah/blob/master/jquery.ghostFaceScrollah.js) that scrolls images or other elements through a div, like a carousel, on a set interval.  I wanted this plugin to work with multiple instances on one page, but when I call it on multiple elements, only the last initialized element scrolls.  I assume the way I'm using setInterval is the cause, but I don't understand why.

The function for scrolling is as follows, and the full source is linked above.

```
function scrollRight() {
    // Don't animate if the mouse is over the scrollah
    if (hovering) { return; }

    /* If we're at the end, flip back to the first image
     * before animating, lest we view blankness in the wrapper
     */
    if (position === nChildren) {
        position = 0;
        $wrapper.css('left', '0px');
    }

    // Animate to the next view
    position++;
    $wrapper.animate({
        left: position*-width+'px'
    }, 1000, 'swing', function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
}
setInterval(scrollRight, 5000);
```

So why do individual instances of this plugin not scroll once more have been initialized?

Comment: Need to see more code, namely the definitions of `$wrapper` and other vars.

Comment: have you tried wrapping the first argument into an anonymous function : `setInterval(function(){scrollRight();},5000);` ?

Comment: @gion_13, that would make no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you change `$wrapper = $this.find('.wrapper');` to `var $wrapper = $this.find('.wrapper');` it might work.

Learned this the other day from Stack Overflow: variables that don't use the `var` keyword are implicitly global in scope, so I think each scroller is overwriting the same global `$wrapper` variable.

EDIT: might also want to do `var $this = $(this);`.